# jQuery: Pull link target and attach it to background class

Tags: jquery, class, hyperlink, background, href

I'm trying to pull a link from a text description in Squarespace and attach it to a background class I created so the whole area is clickable. Nothing I've tried will work at all.

Below is the full script which surfaces the description (which SQSP doesn't usually do) but this is one of the things I've tried among the many to make the entire background area clickable.

```
 $(window).load(function() {
    $('<div class = "desc-wrapper"></div>').appendTo('.margin-wrapper');
    $('.sqs-gallery-design-grid-slide a[data-description]').each(function(index, el) {
        var $el = $(el),
            desc = $el.data('description');   
        $el.after($('<div class = "image-slide-description">'+desc+'</div>'));

        $('.image-slide-description p').addClass('.desc-wrapper');

        $('.desc-wrapper').click(function() {
            window.location = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
            return false;
       });
    });
 });
```

Here's the HTML that's generated by the platform:

```
<div class="slide sqs-gallery-design-grid-slide" data-type="image" id="yui_3_17_2_3_1429494555451_956">
       <div class="margin-wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_3_1429494555451_955">
            <a data-title="Title" data-description="<p><a target=&quot;_blank&quot; href=&quot;http://pitchfork.com&quot;>I am bad at life. But life is bad. But it gets better. There's no win-wn.</a></p>" href="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5498e617e4b0c49940a535ef/54adbb5ae4b0a1c60d2da9c4/54adbb5ee4b0c9b72f217dc8/1426209403214/_MG_6193.jpg" class="image-slide-anchor content-fill" id="yui_3_17_2_3_1429494555451_954" style="overflow: hidden;">
              <noscript>&lt;img src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5498e617e4b0c49940a535ef/54adbb5ae4b0a1c60d2da9c4/54adbb5ee4b0c9b72f217dc8/1426209403214/_MG_6193.jpg"  alt="Title"  /&gt;</noscript><img class="thumb-image loaded" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5498e617e4b0c49940a535ef/54adbb5ae4b0a1c60d2da9c4/54adbb5ee4b0c9b72f217dc8/1426209403214/_MG_6193.jpg" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/5498e617e4b0c49940a535ef/54adbb5ae4b0a1c60d2da9c4/54adbb5ee4b0c9b72f217dc8/1426209403214/_MG_6193.jpg" data-image-dimensions="1391x1800" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-load="false" data-image-id="54adbb5ee4b0c9b72f217dc8" data-type="image" alt="Title" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5498e617e4b0c49940a535ef/54adbb5ae4b0a1c60d2da9c4/54adbb5ee4b0c9b72f217dc8/1426209403214/_MG_6193.jpg?format=300w&amp;storage=local" data-image-resolution="300w" style="opacity: 1; top: -35px; left: 0px; width: 238px; height: 308px; position: relative;">
            </a><div class="image-slide-description"><p class=".desc-wrapper"><a target="_blank" href="http://pitchfork.com">I am bad at life. But life is bad. But it gets better. There's no win-wn.</a></p></div>
       <div class="image-slide-title">Title</div>
   <div class="desc-wrapper"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @maraca, no need for semicolon

Comment: Can you post html snippet?

Comment: I know, corrected immediately after posting, also `$('.desc-wrapper').click(function() {` should be moved one block down probably. With correct indentation you would see what's going on.